# How to access nested structure using pointer and array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned char b[10];
    unsigned char c;
}acc1;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char z[10];
    acc1 *x,y[10];
}acc2;

extern acc2 p[2];
```

I want to access `struct acc1` variables from `acc2` array `p[2]`.

I'm getting segmenatation faults when I do it. Please guide on how to do this

Comment: "_segmenatation fault problem is coming many times_" -- Please show your code.

Comment: Note that `x` is a pointer to `acc1` while `y` is an array of 10 `acc1`, not an array of pointers. Maybe it is what you want, maybe not. These cases are better written in separated lines: `acc1 *x; acc1 y[10];`.

Comment: strcpy(p[0].x->b,"1024"); getting segmantation fault on this what to do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `y`'s elements do:

```
char c = p[some index between 0 and 1].y[some index between 0 and 9].c
```

To access elements referred to by `x` do:

```
size_t i = some index between 0 and 1;
p[i].x = malloc(somenumber_of_elements * sizeof *p[i].x);
if (NULL == p[i].x)
{
  abort(); /* Failure to allocate memory. */
}
char c = p[i].x[some index less then somenumber_of_elements].c;
```

---

Referring *kabhis* comment

> p[0].x->c is it not correct ?

Assuming the allocation above with `somenumber_of_elements` greater `0`, then:

```
char c = p[i].x[0].c;
```

is equivalent to

```
char c = p[i].x->c;
```

and for `somenumber_of_elements` greater `1`

```
char c = p[i].x[1].c;
```

is equivalent to

```
char c = (p[i].x + 1)->c;
```

and so on ...

Comment: @kabhis: How did `p[0].x` got initialised? Also this might be worth another question.

Comment: typedef struct  {    unsigned char addr[20];  }access1;                    typedef struct { acess1   *st   }access2;                                                   access2  arr[8] , *abb[10];  abb[i]=arr;                                                                                                     then how can i access  addr[20]                                                        printf("%s",abb[i]->st->addr);///// how to print these values.

Comment: I do not see how this is related to the question. You might want to pose another question for this.